# ld: file not found: /Library/Developer/.../libclang_rt.ubsan_osx_dynamic.dylib

Tags: xcode, macos, clang, ubsan

I'm trying to use the Undefined Behavior Sanitizer by building like this

```
gcc -fsanitize=undefined add.c -o add
```

also

```
clang -fsanitize=undefined -O add.c -o add
```

In both cases, I'm getting a file not found error:

```
ld: file not found: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.ubsan_osx_dynamic.dylib
```

This is the output I get when running `gcc -v` and `clang -v`

```
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

According to [this news release](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/10/16/gcc-undefined-behavior-sanitizer-ubsan/), it is available in GCC and also the [original homepage](https://embed.cs.utah.edu/ioc/) for it says it's been merged into LLVM. The linked to article says GCC 4.9 has it, which I assume I have (at least --the version numbering seems different but the article was written a few years ago and I have updated my system several times).

Question: how can I build an executable to use UBSan?

Comment: You don't have gcc, you have clang masquerading as gcc. It should still work though. Are you sure you got a complete install of XCode?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I have command line tools installed, not xcode

Comment: there's an article on the llvm blog (http://blog.llvm.org/2013/04/testing-libc-with-fsanitizeundefined.html)  about it but it seems to require building several libraries (libc++ libc++abi) at the risk of overwriting key system libraries, so I haven't tried it (and therefore won't be answering my own question)

Comment: I had the same issue with the `-fsanitize=undefined` flag. Upgrading to `Xcode 10.0` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to blog [Friday Q&A 2015-07-03: Address Sanitizer
by Mike Ash](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-03-address-sanitizer.html):

> > Any idea why Apple clang doesn't support `-fsanitize=undefined`?
> >
> > When I try that I get:
> >
> > ```
> > clang -fsanitize=undefined ub.c
> > ...
> > ld: file not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/
> > bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.ubsan_osx_dynamic.dylib
> > ```
>
> Spencer at 2016-12-21 01:23:59:
>
> If you use `-fsanitize=address,undefined` it works. Hopefully this
>   helps anyone else who finds this post search for that error like I did.

Its not an ideal solution for us since they are separate components, and we have limited control over the environment and tools. We had to suspend some Address Sanitizer testing because Asan produces incorrect results with GCC inline assembly and use of ebp/rbp as a general purpose register. And here, the environment and tools are provided by [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/noloader/cryptopp/jobs/236976227).

---

A bug report was filed with LLVM at [Issue 33201, Apple Clang bundled with Xcode 8 does not reject -fsanitize=undefined when it should](https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=33201). It may be closed as off-topic since its an Apple Clang bug (we don't have an iTunes account to file the bug with Apple).

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the undefined behavior sanitizer, I had to install and build LLVM with clang as well as libcxx and libcxxabi, even though my MacOS already came with a version of clang. (with the result that I now I have two versions of clang installed on my computer). From the [llvm getting started page](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html)

```
cd where-you-want-llvm-to-live
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm

cd where-you-want-llvm-to-live
cd llvm/tools
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk clang

cd where-you-want-llvm-to-live
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk libcxx
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxxabi/trunk libcxxabi
```

Now, I can use the undefined behavior sanitizer by running

```
/usr/local/bin/clang -fsanitize=undefined -O add.c -o add
```